# Error: Stopping ADB Server Failed (Code -1) {Installing API's - Android SDK}

Tags: android, sdk

I am in the process of Downloading and installing the most recent Android API's and System images on my recent install of Android SDK.

While downloading the API's, I ran across an error fairly quickly into the install.

```
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 13
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 13
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 13
```

The Error is this one:

**Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).**

I am curious, will this effect the outcome of the installation? It says that it installed, and it continued onto the next API, so did this effect it?

I assume this happened because I am downloading the API's over a Tethered Android mobile device right now, which is indeed dependent on ADB to tether to the computer. So if it were to stop, it would cancel the download, making the install impossible anyway.

So really, the main question is whether this will effect the installation, not being able to stop ADB while installing and downloading the API's.

And if this will effect the install, couldn't I just follow the links listed for each API' download manually and install manually? Considering I am on the Mobile Device I treat every bit as gold. Despite the fact I have an unlimited data plan, I prefer to not be one of the ones who get capped for being in the top 5%, which actually happened to me on my old AT&T plan.

So any way to be able to do this once, and do it without stopping ADB, would be great. 
Just need your thoughts folks.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: According to http://www.sitepoint.com/beginning-android-install-an-android-platform/, that error message occurs "because the ADB server isn’t running at this point." Which implies you can safely ignore it. The dev team should really let you know that this error doesn't represent a problem, instead of hiliting it in red, as they still do today.

Comment: @LarsH - this seems to be the correct answer. I wish it was the accepted answer. It would have saved me (and others) time. The accepted answer is confusing to say the least.

Comment: @stepanian: I'll add that as an answer, in case it helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the after installing all the packages, the download manager restarts the ADB service. In your case, it appears that the download manager was not able to stop the adb service. If i were to validate the installation,

1. I would just kick off the installation again, and this time i'll probably see lot of packages already installed. If something missing, i'll get a chance to install it.
2. You can always manually restart the adb service to see if it restarts clean without any error.

Comment: Okay, after it installs everything that should be fine to restart the ADB service. It is just needed during the download because it wont restart the tethering service again if it were to stop. but it no longer needs to run once finished so to stop when finished is no problem. I will try to manually restart when the time comes.  So should I just try to restart the service once all is downloaded and the installation is finished? or in between each download?

Comment: Just restart it after all the download and installation is finished.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks, I will let you know as soon as it finishes. only like 5-10 minutes left.

Comment: Okay so the installation seemed to have finished correctly, except for 3 packages. The "Google API's 16 Revision 2", "Google USB Driver", and "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager". But I dont think it had anything to do with the ADB service. Because in the logs, it didn't even show up as downloading, and the ADB successfully restarted itself at the end of the installation without losing connection whatsoever surprisingly. I guess Ill try those 3 again, and if things work out ill mark your answer bud. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Just letting you know, It worked fine. When the ADB Service restarted, it did end the tethering service as expected, but everything was finished installing at the time so it didn't matter, so everything worked out great. Everything is installed, and working great in Eclipse, Motodev, etc. Now time for ADK.  Thank you for your help sit, I greatly Appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

According to http://sitepoint.com/beginning-android-install-an-android-platform, that error message occurs "because the ADB server isn’t running at this point." Which implies you can safely ignore it: The ADB server doesn't need to be running; the installation process is just trying to stop it if it *is* running.

Seems to me the dev team should really let you know that this error **doesn't** represent a problem, instead of highlighting it in red, as they still do (as of Dec. 2014).

Comment: They still do it now. I would like to call it a bug.

Comment: @FranklinYu: If you find or create a bug tracker entry for it, I will gladly vote for it.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but still quite relevant. @ insomnia, if you read this, please mark this answer as the correct one. It could save someone a lot of time and worry.

Answer (score 0):

I also was tethering and was unable to have adb start in Android Studio.  Since, it has started for tethering, it seems as though it is a conflict for Android Studio to restart it.