# Android Studio 1.5.1 Setup

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Hi guys I'm trying to install `Android Studio 1.5.1` by following `Standard` setup phases but having the following error. I've `JDK version 1.7`:
[image]

Comment: because your sdk platform is latest one that support jdk 1.8, and also upgrade android studio version 1.5.1 to  2.1.2, bcz 1.5.1 is history now.

Comment: let's say I need to use 1.5.1 would using jdk 1.8 solve the problem of this setup?

Comment: yes.. bcz without latest jdk you cant use this new features. or you can use 1.5.1 if you want.  i seems you dont want instant run feature or other facility..

Comment: I am going to use both 1.5.1 and 2.1 thanks

Comment: and yes.. apply Atul Mavani's answer.. this will solve your problem for sure..  bcz i forget to mention about this thing..

Comment: this might be help to you..  bcz i dont know about mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089697/how-to-set-java-jdk-environment-variable-for-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if it failed to stop the adb service at one point during installation. I would simply try running the installation as second time, and then it should skim over the already-installed components and install the missing one.

Similar post on stackoverflow: [Error: Stopping ADB Server Failed (Code -1) {Installing API's - Android SDK}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572577/error-stopping-adb-server-failed-code-1-installing-apis-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this step.

set the path of jdk using following step.

1. property of my computer
2. click on advanced system setting
3. click on environment variable
4. find path variable on system variable
5. set below path on path variable

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
 then check it on cmd 
by entering command javac.

its helpfull for you.

Comment: sorry for not specifying but I'm using mac