# Issue with SDK Manager and Android Tools adb.exe with Game Maker 1.4

Tags: android, sdk, adb, android-sdk-manager, game-maker-studio-1.4

I don't know why but I cant install the adb.exe I have this issue :

[image]

And in game maker this issue:

[image]

What's odd is that at the beginning it recognized me the android SDK, and after a few builds it stopped working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend seeing if that service is actually running and has already been installed, in which I would: Kill it. Restart SDK manager. Try installing it again. Based on this information here: [Error: Stopping ADB Server Failed (Code -1) {Installing API's - Android SDK}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572577/error-stopping-adb-server-failed-code-1-installing-apis-android-sdk)